# Commutativity and $(a + b)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read "note that if a and b are commutative, $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$".

Could someone explain how we need commutativity for this to happen?

Comment: there will be term $ab+ba$ if you expand

Comment: When you're multiplying the brackets out, you assume $ab = ba$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand it termwise:

$$(a+b)^2 = (a+b) \cdot (a+b) = a \cdot a + \color{blue}{a \cdot b} + \color{red}{b \cdot a} + b\cdot b$$

Commutativity assures us that $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$ so that the expression becomes

$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$

Without commutativity, we have to leave our answer as it is in the first expression, we cannot simplify it to the second expression.

Comment: So basically $a^2+ab+ba+b^2$ might not be $a^2+2ab+b^2$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are matrices. Then it might really happen (see the comments) that $A^2+AB+BA+B^2$ is not equal to $A^2+2AB+B^2$. For example, take $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \;B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $AB\neq BA$.

There is no statement in the question about the algebraic structure to which $a$ and $b$ belong.